# What WinAPI feature could change the width of window border on Win7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm just noticed that a new version of my app has broader borders on Windows 7 (there is no difference in Win10):
[image: Screenshot]

The background window is my new version and the foreground window is an older version.

I'm trying to find difference in git, but with no luck yet. I have tried to set different border styles in resource editor of Visual Studio, e.g. `None`, `Thin`, `Resizing` etc. - it does change nothing. Also I have tried to set different styles via `SetWindowLong` (I found examples somewhere in SO):

```
 LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(mainWindow.GetWindowHandle(), GWL_STYLE);
 lStyle &= ~(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
 SetWindowLong(mainWindow.GetWindowHandle(), GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

 LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(mainWindow.GetWindowHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE);
 lExStyle &= ~(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE);
 SetWindowLong(mainWindow.GetWindowHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
```

While changing the style I can change only the presence of titlebar, buttons, etc., but borders' size on Win7 always remains the same.

**UPDATE:** Answer to commenters.

@Junjie Zhu. I didn't change `PaddedBorderWidth`. I suppose it controls all applications, but I can run both versions of my app simultaneously and older version will have thin borders, and newer version will have thick borders.

@Paul Sanders and @Anders. I have checked manifest file - the only difference is that I had added DPI-awareness setting for Win10:

```
<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
```

I have tried to remove it - nothing had changed. All other strings in manifest file are the same. Specifically, it has all fields for supporting Os'es from WinVista to Win10/11:

```
<compatibility
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

I cann't imagine which of other fields can control borders' size.

Comment: Did you perhaps change the application manifest?  I don't know of anything in there specifically that would relate to this, but it's a place to look.

Comment: Vista added border padding. Not sure if Windows removes it for apps it thinks are incompatible.

Comment: @Anders Good thinking, and marking an app as 'compatible' *is* done in the manifest.

Comment: Have you tried to modify `PaddedBorderWidth` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop/WindowMetrics`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've found the reason - I have switched `Platform toolset` from `v120_xp` to the latest `v143`. May be somebody knows how to retain thin borders with new toolset?

**UPDATE:** Wow! Thanks to Hans Passant! When using newer version of toolset just set `Minimum required version` to 5.02. Now it works.

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > System > "Minimum required version" = 5.02